# Qt5 undefined reference to `QString

Tags: gcc, qt5, qstring

I have a sensor that in their SDK, they are calling QT5 package.

This is the GCC command to  build the program`gcc Main.c -o main -L../../Release -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lQt5SerialPort -lLeddarC -lLeddar -lLeddarTech -lstdc++`

But after that I'm getting these errors:

```
../../Release/libLeddar.so: undefined reference to `QString::toLocal8Bit_helper(QChar const*, int)'
../../Release/libLeddarC.so: undefined reference to `QString::toUtf8_helper(QString const&)'
../../Release/libLeddarC.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8'
```

I think Qstring is a part of QtCore, I tired to find it to add to gcc but I just find `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtCore.so.4` that is basically based on Qt4 and not 5.

I aleady found the location of `Qt5SerialPort`  at `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` .But I don't know why I'm getting error for `QString`
Could you please help me with solving this issue?

When I look for `QString` I got this:

```
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QStringRef
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QStringData
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QStringBuilder
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QStringMatcher
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QStringList
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QStringListModel
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QStringDataPtr
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QString
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QStringListIterator
```

It seems that They are in include folder but I don't know how I can call them with GCC since they are not build `*.so` libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Think you need add new -lQtCore option to gcc command.

Comment: the issue is that I can not find libQtcore.so on my system to address it first with -L and then call it with -l

Comment: Then  you need install or build appropriate set of Qt libraries.

Comment: May I know how I can install QtCore?